# CSS Tooltip in div with `overflow: scroll` being cut off and hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm currently developing my first application with HTML and CSS and in there, I'm developing a scrollable item list. Each item in the list has a tooltip positioned absolutely in relation to the image, in order to change its position with the scroll. However when the `overflow` is set to `scroll`, the left tooltip is cut off, the right one enables scroll on the X axis and the scroll goes all the way to the bottom, with the tooltip size interfering.

The bottom part extends to fit the tooltip, the left part is hidden and the right part is also hidden, but scrollable:

[image: The bottom part extends to fit the tooltip, the left part is hidden and the right part is also hidden, but scrollable]

The current structure of the HTML is:

```
<div id="item-list">
  <div id="item-search">//Here comes a simple search bar</div>

  <div id="item-options">
    <div class="item-container">
      <img src="itemsImages/1001.png" class="item-images" />
      <span class="item-tooltip">
        <maintext>
          <stats> <attention>25</attention> Move Speed </stats> </maintext
        ><br />
      </span>
    </div>

    After that comes all the other items.
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#item-options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  font-size: 0;
}

#item-options div {
  width: 10%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.item-images {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.item-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-break: normal;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
  font-size: 12px;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.item-container img:hover ~ .item-tooltip {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I tried to change only the `overflow-y` option, however it remained the same. I took out the `relative` position of the `div` and the overflow problem was gone, but when scrolling, the item tooltip was out of position.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have the tooltip element outside the scrolling container. You can use JavaScript to trigger the appearance of the tooltip. You will probably also want to use JavaScript to control the position of the tooltip when the scrolling container is scrolled.

```js
const image = document.querySelector('.item-images');
const tooltip = document.querySelector('.item-tooltip');

image.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  tooltip.style.opacity = '1';
});
image.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  tooltip.style.opacity = '0';
});
```

```css
#item-options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  font-size: 0;
}

#item-options div {
  width: 10%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.item-images {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.item-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-break: normal;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
  font-size: 12px;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="item-list">

  <div id="item-search">
    //Here comes a simple search bar
  </div>

  <div id="item-options">
    <div class="item-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" class="item-images">
    </div>

    After that comes all the other items.
  </div>
</div>

<span class="item-tooltip">
  <maintext>
    <stats>
      <attention>25</attention> Move Speed
    </stats>
  </maintext><br>
</span>
```

Comment: I'm currently using a tooltip for each item, in that case i create a bunch of spans for each one and work around with JS? Also, thank u, i'm going to search a bit more about how to do this integration.

Comment: You'd create a bunch of `span`s for each one and work around with JS.